# Different Content for Different Browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have made a wordpress website, and I have added a video on my page and masked it. On firefox & chrome it works perfectly. But on safari, it shows a play button inside the mask. I am not able to find a solution for that, so I thought if I could just change the content for safari. I don't know if its possible or not, but if I can just put an image for safari and video for others.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Using of video has many policies in each browser engine !
safari and apple using Webkit and webkit and apple has some policies for  tag
you should learn this policies here [Webkit Policies For](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

some attribute like playsinline may help you and also you should know that if you want to make your video autoplay then should use autoplay attribute and also the for user policy you should use muted attribute or ask for an unmuted video before playing